# How to randomly assign values in an array to dict.key?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to write some code that randomly assigns values in a 1D array to keys in a dict, and then later calls both keys in random order. Its not very elegant, but so far I've done this by creating an array:

```
array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

randomizing its contents:

```
shuffle(array)
```

and then assigning different ranges of indices in the (now shuffled) array to keys in a dict:

```
a = array[0:2]
b = array[3:5]
dict = {'cond_A':a,'cond_B':b}
```

the code reliably works up until this point (tested by printing `dict.get('cond_A')` and `dict.get('cond_B')`

However, I then try to call values from each key as separate sets, presented in random order, with:

```
x = random.choice(dict.keys())
first_set = dict.get(x) 
if x == dict['cond_A']:
    second_set = dict.get('cond_B')
else:
    second_set = dict.get('cond_A')
```

Sometimes this works in that `first_set` and `second_set` contain different (non-overlapping) values, as intended. However, half the time both sets contain identical values (that do not correspond to the printed `dict.get` values from earlier). For example, the output might look like this on a successful run:

```
a == [1,3,4]
b == [6,2,5]

first_set == [1,3,4]
second_set == [6,2,5]
```

but on the next run, it might look like:

```
a == [1,3,4]
b == [6,2,5]

first_set == [1,3,4]
second_set == [1,3,4]
```

Clearly my if-else function is not consistently working as intended, but I have no idea why. Does anyone know why this might be the case? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `x == dict['cond_A']` cannot possibly ever be true in your code.  The left side is one of `'cond_A'` or `'cond_B'`, the right side is a list of three ints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem by referencing a and b with `== get.dict()` and then replacing the else function with elif:

```
x = random.choice(dict.keys())
first_set = dict.get(x)

if first_set == dict.get('cond_A'):
    second_set = dict.get('cond_B')
elif first_set == dict.get('cond_B'):
    second_set = dict.get('cond_A')
```

Leaving this here for future users :)